# Boost C++: Seeding random numbers in a function

Tags: c++, boost, seed

I have a function that should simulate a new random exponential variable every time it is called:

```
 #include <boost/random.hpp>    

//Simulates a single exponential random variable                                                            
double generateExponential(double lambda) {
      boost::mt19937 rng; //Mersenne Twister Generator                                                          
      rng.seed(time(0));                                                           
      boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937&, boost::exponential_distribution<> > rndm(rng, boost::exponenti\
    al_distribution<>(lambda));
      return rndm();
  }
```

for example,

```
double newExp = generateExponential(10);
```

However, each time I call the function, it generates *the same* random number. I want it to generate a different random number each time the function is called. I thought "rng.seed(time(0))" might fix it but it hasn't. How could I get it to do this?

Comment: You keep feeding it the seed, every time you call it. So it generates the same value, every time you call it. time(0) doesn't change often between clock cycles.

Comment: note that `mt19937` was added to C++11; if you have C++11 available then you can improve on this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the signature of your function, then you could use a `static` instance of your generator.  No need to re-seed.

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>

typedef boost::mt19937 G;
typedef boost::exponential_distribution D;

double generateExponential(double lambda)
{
  static G rng(std::time(0)); // initialized and seeded once
  boost::variate_generator<G &, D<> > rndm(rng, D<>(lambda));
  return rndm();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. Just wondering, since we're making rng a static, would it work the same to just define it outside the function?

Comment: Yes, then it would be a global.  As others have mentioned, you can also pass an instance of the generator as an argument to the function.

Comment: I'd be rather suspicious of this approach if you used random number generators elsewhere in your program too.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a source of random numbers should be a resource whose lifespan is that of your *entire program*, not that of an individual function call.

Consequently, you need the object representing said source of random numbers to have an appropriate lifespan. Making it a variable local to your function is a Bad Idea. It should be an object passed into your function, or maybe a global object.

(also, frequently reseeding a random number generator is another well known Bad Idea)

Comment: Thanks!
So do you think I should do "boost::mt1937 rng;" in the main() function, specify rng.seed(time(0)) in the main function, and just leave the remaining lines for the generateExponential function?